# How to install Xen-Tools on Ubuntu Server LTS 16.04 with Xenserver 7?

Tags: 16.04, server, virtualization, xen

I tried several methods.

1. `sudo apt-get install xen-tools` is installing at least two packages but cannot configure / start them for unknown reason.

   [Source](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/xen-tools)
2. Using the iso provided by Xencenter (developer help page)

   ```
   mount /dev/xvdd /mnt
   ```

   End up this way

   ```
   mount: special device /dev/xvdd does not exist
   ```

   [Source](https://docs.citrix.com/fr-fr/xencenter/6-5/xs-xc-vms-configuring/xs-xc-vms-installtools.html)
3. Using the iso provided by Xencenter (xen ochestra help page)

   ```
   mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
   ```

   works

   ```
   bash /mnt/Linux/install.sh
   ```

   returns

   ```
   bash: /mnt/Linux/install.sh: No such file or directory
   ```

   [Source](https://xen-orchestra.com/blog/install-xenserver-tools-in-your-vm/)

Comment: I mounted the iso via /dev/cdrom found the solution here:
https://xen-orchestra.com/blog/install-xenserver-tools-in-your-vm/

Answer (score 9):

You first need to find out the physical path to the DVD drive by running:

```
sudo lsblk -f
```

The output can look like this:

```
NAME                 FSTYPE      LABEL           UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sr0                  iso9660     XenServer Tools 2017-02-14-21-45-52-00
xvda
├─xvda1              ext2                        b874af3a-24ec-454f-a802-0fee2945e388   /boot
├─xvda2
└─xvda5              LVM2_member                 LOmK2X-RYRD-GR8s-Guzv-kXFN-e3Y8-gSVdgM
  ├─nginx--vg-root   ext4                        2dd0c496-ea05-4027-bf90-84ceb94d2f3a   /
  └─nginx--vg-swap_1 swap                        77064139-1d50-4344-ade7-dacec1e62c9b   [SWAP]
```

As you can see, I already "inserted" the Xen Tools disk and the drive has `/dev/sr0` physical path. Then, you need to create a directory where the drive will be mounted and then mount it:

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/dvd
$ sudo mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/dvd
mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

Then, run the installer

```
cd /mnt/dvd/Linux
sudo ./install.sh
```

Comment: maybe you net explicit type `sudo mount /dev/sr0 -t iso9660 /mnt/dvd`

Answer (score 1):

You can currently install version 6.2 (Which works with XenServer 7.2) with apt:

```
sudo apt-get install xe-guest-utilities
```

Though, as this will then get upgraded (either via `apt-get updgrade` or unattended-upgrades), it may become unstable when a new version of XenServer is released, so it may be good to pin it to version 6.* (/etc/apt/preferences.d/xe-guest-utilities):

```
Package: xe-guest-utilities
Pin: version 6.*
Pin-Priority: 900
```